# Speed up appearance of all context menus in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

When I right-click on Windows 10 desktop and put my mouse cursor over "New" then I have to wait about 0.5 seconds for the context menu to appear.

In software such as Notepad++ all menus also appear with the same delay. E.g. to reach "Edit > EOL Conversion" I have to wait 0.5 seconds for the sub-menu to appear.

Would it be possible to make all menus appear instantly with 0 seconds delay and with no animations? I tried to set "Adjust for best performance" in "Performance Options" but that doesn't remove the delay.

I have a high-end computer and I have few applications so it's not their fault.

Comment: Does this same delay occur on other menus/submenus on your computer? How many different entries are there in your "New" submenu?

Comment: May be your context menu become full of other installed softwares. Remove some of those unwanted context menu options.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is controlled by a registry value under:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop**

Find the key "**MenuShowDelay**", and you'll see the default value is 400 (this means 400 milliseconds). **I usually set it to 0 to get instant menus**. Change the value, then reboot your computer to have it take effect.

Answer (score -1):

You can change this by modifying the registry.

- Open `regedit.exe`
- Browse to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`
- Modify the key `MouseHoverTime`

The default value is 400 (ms).

Edit: Just in case it wasn't obvious, make the number smaller to decrease the time you have to wait.

Comment: 400 ms is nearly a half of a second. I am sure there is a minimum value.

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't recommend a value less than zero...

Comment: Because you will start seeing the menu before you click?

Comment: Cause and effect might never be the same.

Comment: This setting is for [taskbar hover preview](https://visihow.com/Speed_up_Mouse_Hover_Time_for_Taskbar_Preview_of_Thumbnails_in_Windows_7). It does not seem to affect context menus.

Comment: Setting the value to `0` or so is dangerous if you have a multi-row taskbar. Then the *context menu* (which appears above all rows) of a lower-row app gets replaced by the *preview* of a higher-row app when you move your mouse towards the context menu.